# Initialization from incompatible pointer type when assigning struct file_operations fields

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I'm writing a Linux device drive and I'm confused as to why I'm getting this warning.

```
error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  .write = file_write,
```

This is my code that I created, when I use make command I get the above error. I tried changing `ssize_t` to `int` but still I get the same error.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/random.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("NIKS");


static char msg[100]={0};
static short readPos =0;

static int file_open(struct inode * , struct file *);
static int file_release(struct inode * , struct file *);
static ssize_t file_read(struct file *, char *, size_t,loff_t * );
static ssize_t file_write(struct file *, char *, size_t,loff_t * );

static struct file_operations fo = 
{
    .read = file_read,
    .open = file_open,
    .write = file_write,
    .release = file_release,
};

int init_module(void)
{
    int t = register_chrdev(150,"encdev",&fo);
    if(t<0)
    {
        printk("error");
    }
    else
    {
        printk("success");
    }
    return t;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    unregister_chrdev(150,"encdev");
}

static int file_open(struct inode *in , struct file *fil)
{
    return 0;
}

static ssize_t file_read(struct file *fil, char *buf, size_t len,loff_t *off )
{
    short count=0;
    printk("here %d",msg[0]!=0);
    while(len && (msg[readPos]!=0))
    {
        printk("read");
        put_user(msg[readPos],buf++);
        count++;
        len--;
        readPos++;
    }
    return count;
}

static ssize_t file_write(struct file *fil, char *buf, size_t len,loff_t *off )
{
    short ind = 0;
    short count =0;
    memset(msg,0,100);
    readPos = 0;
    int i =0;
    char bytes[16];
    char rand;
    while(i<16)
    {
        get_random_bytes(&rand, sizeof(rand));
        bytes[i]=rand;
        ++count;
        i++;
    }
    int _len = len+16;
    while(_len>0 || count%16){
        if(ind<16) msg[ind] = bytes[ind];
        else{
            msg[ind] = (_len>0?buf[ind-16]:'@')^msg[ind-16];
        }
        ++ind;
        --_len;
        ++count;
    }
    return count;

}

static int file_release(struct inode *in , struct file *fil)
{
    printk("done");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm new to C and I just can't work out why I'm getting this warning. Can anybody explain why I get this warning and what to do about it please?

Comment: Usually these errors are based on the compiler command line you use, version of the compiler, target, environment etc. Can you also include the compiler command line and related details in the question. Welcome to stack overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct types for the `read` and `write` function pointers of [`struct file_operations`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.10/source/include/linux/fs.h#L1821) are:

```
ssize_t (*read) (struct file *, char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
ssize_t (*write) (struct file *, const char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
```

Therefore, in your module, the appropriate signatures are:

```
static ssize_t file_read(struct file *, char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
static ssize_t file_write(struct file *, const char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);

// ...

static ssize_t file_read(struct file *fil, char __user *buf, size_t len,loff_t *off)
{

// ...

static ssize_t file_write(struct file *fil, const char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *off)
{
```

The important part that was missing was the `const` qualifier, but it's also important to remember that any pointer passed from userspace should be marked with the `__user` annotation (even though the compiler will not warn you if you forget it, it's only meant to be used as a static check for [Sparse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse)).

---

You also have several declarations after other stataments, which is invalid in C90. The compiler will warn you about those, follow the warnings and move them to the top of the function body.